# Socket.io handle online/offline status

Tags: node.js, socket.io

I've a real time chat application i've implemented it using socket.io, nodejs and angularJS but i'm having issues while handling the online/offline status. I'm not clear on how to know when the user is online or offline. What i thought is hitting a api in every 3 seconds and update the online/offline status in the database but i don't feel it's a good way so is there any better way to handle it?

Thanks in advance!

Here is the link to my backend code.
[DesktopChat-Backend](https://github.com/Atishay96/DesktopChat-Backend)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to hit every 3 seconds , socket.io do this automatically, so you have just to handle it inside on. ('connection') and on.('disconnect'), so you get the user connected or disconnected then you broadcast the information to the clients, and update their status.

Look at this example : 
[Showing online users using Nodejs and Socket.io and angular js](http://www.codershood.info/2015/12/10/showing-online-users-using-nodejs-socket-io/)

[One-to-One-Chat-using-Node.js-Socket-IO-Library](https://github.com/Sumanvit33/One-to-One-Chat-using-Node.js-Socket-IO-Library/blob/master/index.js)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I didn't find the logic which he used useful, still can you explain your point here?

Comment: you don't need to hit every 3 seconds , socket.io do this automatically, so you have just to handle it inside on. ('connection') and on.('disconnect'), then you get the user connected or disconnected then you broadcast the information to the clients

Comment: but how will you know if someone kills page or app how will you handle it then? socket.io disconnect? on socket.io disconnect you'll get the socket.io connection id

Comment: oh! i got the answer i'll store the socket.io id in redis then it'll work.

Comment: when you close the page the disconnect event is sent to the server

Comment: Yeah but how will you know for which user it came until or unless you store the socket id in redis server?

Comment: yes you can store it some where else, instead of storing it in an array as he did in the example in the link i gave you (var clients=new Array();), Redis is a good choice

Answer (score 0):

you can make map, where your userId will be associated with all socket.io client ids for this user. Then you can just look into this map, if specific user has some open connections.